# Protecting AES key in mobile App

Tags: android, iphone, aes

I have read through a number of posts and resources regarding AES, CommonCryptor, salt and MAC in search of a solution to a problem I am facing with the release of my mobile software library. I would like to pass an encrypted string to my iPhone and Android App via HTML and JavaScript in a WebView using custom URL Scheme, with the string as a parameter. The HTML file will be created on my site and then distributed to users to store on their web servers.

From what I have read, I would encrypt the string in the HTML file using a key before distributing it to the user. Then the same key would be stored in the library and used to decrypt the string. But if someone decompiles my App they would then have the key and be able to decrypt the string stored in the distributed HTML file.  I know that the library can be easily decompiled, but providing the string along with the code is really giving it away. And the real danger it that one could use the HTML files to trigger nefarious actions in a hacked version of my library.

I really don’t want to make a call to my site to get the key or salt and I am not sure that would offer any protection. Would a random salt stored along with the key in the library work?

I am willing to put in the time to research, code and test this, but first I would like to know if this is even feasible using AES, CommonCryptor, salt or MAC. If we solve it here, it will be available to all as the solution to this problem.

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Compile your own openssl and crypro static libraries and include those two static modules into your own native .so module. Don't use internal Android SSL.

Sore the key deep inside in some protected manner (simple solution is to use an array of floats with some non trivial hashing). Decipher the encrypted messages in the native code. Decide whenever the message is OK or not also inside the native code. Don't return to Java with plain boolean values.

Whenever a hacker wants to crack your code he has to decompile ~800K of native code.

Comment: This is just security through obscurity.

Comment: Thank you both for responding.